# Hide unmatching combinations prestashop

Tags: prestashop-1.6

Title says it all. I have a store (PrestaShop 1.6.0.11) with dozen of combinations, some attributes are compatible with other and some not.
I'd like to hide some attributes depending on the choice of another, which PrestaShop obviously does not as I'm still able to select attributes even if the combination of these attributes is not possible.
Instead it adds a nice warning :

> This combination does not exist for this product. Please select
>   another combination.

You can imagine time to spend if 10 or more combinations are not possible...

I tried to find a solution on the web, even asking on PrestaShop forum, but seems I'm the only one having that issue.

Any idea ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I found a website using PrestaShop with the feature I need : [link](http://www.photo-originale.com/fr/laurent-scheinfeld/201587-en-noir-et-blanc-1.html) Looks like it's related with product.js [link](http://pastebin.com/eiE6pY3i)

Comment: A hint to a module which implement this behaviour would be nice.

Comment: I know it's old, but have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hi @Kiotto sry for the delay. I think I used at that time this plugin [link](https://addons.prestashop.com/en/combinaisons-customization/14160-filterattribute-declination-and-attribute-in-stock.html)